# Изменились уведомления?

Tags: поддержка, репутация, уведомления

Сейчаз заметил, что раньше выводилось суммарная заработанная репа, а теперь изменения. Так ли это? И где смотреть информацию о нововведения на **SOru**?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всегда так было.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ничего не менялось.

Выводится накопленная с последнего просмотра этих уведомлений репутация.

Если не кликать по кубку - число заработанной репутации будет копиться.
Просмотр меню сбрасывает счётчик.